# Should VSCode report errors for TS files that are excluded from compilation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I filed this [Bug Report](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53733#issuecomment-403153218) with VSCode because I have excluded `*.spec` files from compilation since I don't want to include the files in the NPM distribution.

I would still like to see that they compile correctly though via the VSCode tooling.

As it stands VSCode intellisense reports that imports that are available on the path can't be imported and this throws a lot of errors, paints the project spec files red, etc.

In my report, I said that VSCode error reporting and compilation should be two separate issues.  VSCode can't both check that the file is correct and exclude it from compilation at the same time.  The two are not mutually exclusive.

I have asked for triage from VSCode, but so far the issue remains closed and I wanted to see what others on SO though.  Is it a bug or is the conclusion in the report correct as it stands?

Comment: Primarily opinion-based questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: It's a question about workflow.  In other words if having a single tsconfig file makes sense 80% of the time, regardless of excludes, then that's the correct choice.  Having group input on this helps make VSCode better for all of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, right now VS Code uses one language service instance for files not included by `tsconfig.json` (including the case in which `tsconfig.json` does not exist at all) with default compiler options, and when `tsconfig.json` exists, it uses a second language service instance that eagerly loads all included files and uses the specified compiler options.  I believe you are proposing that when `tsconfig.json` exists, the first language service instance should use the compiler options from `tsconfig.json` but have the same file loading behavior it has now.  This would be a marginal increase in complexity, and honestly, the experience of editing files excluded from `tsconfig.json` when `tsconfig.json` exists would still be pretty confusing: some of your files will see global definitions and others won't, and "find all references" will give you partial results.  Your proposal seems to me to be a plausible alternative to the status quo, but I don't see why you are fighting the VS Code team over it rather than just creating two `tsconfig.json` files, which is explicit and gives you the unified editing experience you actually want.  (Or were you proposing that there should be a single language service that ignores the excludes and eagerly loads all `.ts(x?)` files under the project directory?  I'm quite sure that won't fly as it will cause problems in many scenarios.)

Comment: Hi Matt - I see what you are saying.  VSCode is interpreting the files as being completely excluded from the project per the `exclude` option in `tsconfig` and I just want to exclude the file from being outputted to my dist directory.  I still think that the side effect that VSCode starts painting errors all over the project is incorrect.  It should use the same tsconfig file for the excluded files as well, and if the author wants another behavior then they should configure that.  In other words we should only have to create another tsconfig file is absolutely necessary, not just to hack ...

Comment: around the issue.  VSCode is not part of typescript, so if we want to files to be excluded from the intellisense that VSCode provides, I think that should be done in a local VSCode configuration files, otherwise all the configuration in tsconfig should be applied to the ts files.

Comment: I can imagine the opposite argument: "Why is VS Code applying the compiler options from my `tsconfig.json` to my `Gulpfile.ts` when it's explicitly excluded because those options only make sense for my regular source files?"  And there are more cases to consider: if there's no `tsconfig.json` in the workspace root but there's one in a subdirectory, does it apply to excluded files outside that subdirectory?  But this discussion seems moot because you're not going to convince the VS Code team and you probably want unified "find all references", which requires two `tsconfig.json` files anyway.

Comment: Perhaps we want to import project files into `Gulpfile.ts` that are resolved using the path setup in `tsconfig.json`?  That seems like it makes sense.  We want to exclude Gulpfile.ts from the dist output, but still be able to resolve project specific files inside of it.  You might be right about convincing the team.  I just want the conversation / rational to make sense and setup approach to make sense.

Comment: Ultimately I think VSCode should produce examples of cases where usability is harmed.  If these cases don't exist then VSCode should not force us to create additional files.  I think your `Gulpfile.ts` example is great thought material, but does it harm usability if VSCode applies the tsconfig.json settings to the file in general?  And the answer is probably yes there are scenarios, but do those scenarios only occur 1% of the time.  If that's the case then we should only put in additional effort if the scenario occurs.

Comment: Ultimately I think VSCode team should work on things that are worth their time, and a complaint from one user when an easy workaround exists isn't sufficient evidence that they should investigate this further.

Comment: You may be right (I definitely think you are very good at this stuff and have a lot of respect for you), but within the short time period that the issue existed there was already one other user that also said it was causing issues for him.  So we don't really have a good grasp on how many people are affected by it, because the issue was closed right away.  They could have kept it open and allowed it to gather honey, and then we would have a better idea of how it is affecting users.  I did not say I wanted it fixed instantly, just that it would be nice to have it fixed eventually.

Comment: Most people feel this away about learning Javascript these days: https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f      And yet another tsconfig file to setup in order to get the project to publish right just adds to the overall stack of the other million things we have to learn ... Right now my project works fine and compiles fine, but if anyone ever checks it out VSCode will show a gazillion errors in the console log that are not real.

Comment: I don't think it was wrong to close the issue.  It communicates that your proposal is unlikely to be accepted, but not impossible given enough user feedback; VS Code team gets to decide the threshold for closing that makes the open/closed categorization most useful to them.  If additional users are affected, I would expect them to still "thumb up" the issue or comment, or open a new issue if the current one gets automatically locked by a bot such as the TypeScript repo has.  It's not even clear to me at this point that mitchellsimoens had the same issue.

Comment: Good point.  Well - we have it here and there now, so if someone needs to understand the issue, they can see it here and perhaps provide more feedback.  Personally I think that excluding from VSCode should be configured separately, because its causing an unexpected side effect in the tooling.  One minute everything is working fine, and then all of a sudden all the exclude files turn red ... This is not documented I don't think ... So first we have to recognize what's happening, and then we have to research the workaround ...